# PyDrive Quickstart and Error 403: access_denied

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am trying to download google drive photo to my local drive. I thought this should be an easy task but it is practically challenging especially that it is my first time trying to use google API.

Following all the steps in this helpful [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mnKE9IERt4&t=449s) and under this [PyDrive Link](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html)

I reach the step where it says `Rename the file to “client_secrets.json” and place it in your working directory.`

I then run this code

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication.
```

But did not reach anywhere. In particular, I got this error

> Error 403: access_denied The developer hasn’t given you access to this
> app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by
> Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer

I am the developer and I am trying to download my google file (actually a pic) to my local drive.

I am thankful for all the support.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the APIs & Services section and add yourself as an "Test user" in the OAuth consent screen tab.